# Converting ROLLUP to CUBE

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Let's say we have access to `GROUP BY ROLLUP` but not `GROUP BY CUBE` (for example, in mysql or even postgres if we imagine `CUBE` doesn't exist in an older version).

The following shows the difference between `ROLLUP` and `CUBE`:

```
ROLLUP (a, b, c)
(a, b, c)
(a, b)
(a)
()
```

```
CUBE (a, b, c)
(a, b, c)
(a, b)
(a, c)
(a)
(b, c)
(b)
(c)
()
```

If `CUBE` is not an option, what would be the proper way to map the `ROLLUP` function to be `CUBE`? It seems it would be:

```
ROLLUP (a,b,c) UNION ALL
ROLLUP (a,  c) UNION ALL
ROLLUP (  b,c) UNION ALL
ROLLUP (    c)
```

Is that a correct understanding? And if so, would it be possible to use a recursive CTE or something else to emulate the `CUBE` function with rollup for N variables? If so, how could this be done?

Comment: `rollup(a,b,c)` and `rollup(a,c)` will both generate `group by a` and all rollups will generate grand total. Looks like recursive CTE is possible option, but currently I cannot compose such a query

Answer (score 0):

You could use a procedure to generate your sqls

You could try a procedure as below pseudo

```
   Create procedure Rollup(a, b) 
     As
     Begin 
     For i in [a, b, c]    -- or whatever array you may have
          For j! =i
                 Rollup(i, j) 
                 End loop;
      End loop;
    END
```

Comment: @hi -- thanks, what language is that? Also how do you do it with vargs?